# Reduce the number of suggested JavaScript methods when using IntelliJ autocomplete and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete, intellij-idea

I'm building a Node.js application in IntelliJ and have the Node.js plugin installed.

When I type '.' IntelliJ suggests all available methods on the object.

The problem that I am seeing is that it suggests literally 1000 methods to choose from. It suggests methods from scores of different libraries, core HTML JavaScript methods etc... Whereas I just want the methods on my object.

Seeing so many options basically makes autocomplete useless and I end up having to go to the libraries API web page and using that as a reference.

Is there any way to change this behaviour or is that just how it works when autocompleting JavaScript libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried installing a Node.js plugin for IntelliJ and it doesn't seem to work well. Would trying WebStorm be out of the question? They are made by the same company (JetBrains) but WebStorm is specifically geared towards JavaScript and Node.js. When it presents autocomplete results it does show an objects methods at the top of in bold so you can quickly identify and use them.